# Scanner problem: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I try to compile, it highlights with middle sc.next() with "java.lang.String cannot be converted to int."

How do I format it so the scanner can process the middle sc.next as an int?

```
public void loadStationData(){
    String filename = "data/stations.data";
    File stations = new File(filename);
    try{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (stations);
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        station.add(new Station(sc.next(), sc.next(), sc.next()));
    }
}
catch (IOException e){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextInt()` instead:

```
station.add(new Station(sc.next(), sc.nextInt(), sc.next()));
```

Answer (score 0):

can you not use sc.nextInt()?

```
station.add(new Station(sc.next(), sc.nextInt(), sc.next()));
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

If you check the specification for [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) you'll notice that `next()` returns a `String`. Scanner however does have a method specifically for returning an `int`, namely `nextInt()`

```
station.add(new Station(sc.next(), sc.nextInt(), sc.next()));
```